# ora-02270 How do i fix this?

Tags: sql, oracle

This is what I have:

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENTS(
    stu_id NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
    stu_name VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
    stu_address VARCHAR2(15),
    stu_major VARCHAR2(6),
    CONSTRAINT students_pk PRIMARY KEY (stu_id)
);


CREATE TABLE GRADE(
    stu_id NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
    course_id VARCHAR2(7),
    stu_crse_grade VARCHAR2(1),
    PRIMARY KEY (stu_id, course_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (stu_id) REFERENCES students(stu_id),
    CHECK (stu_crse_grade = 'A' 
    AND stu_crse_grade = 'B' 
    AND stu_crse_grade = 'C' 
    AND stu_crse_grade = 'D' 
    AND stu_crse_grade = 'F')
);


CREATE TABLE COURSE(
    course_id VARCHAR2(7),
    course_title VARCHAR2(20),
    instructor_id NUMBER(3),
    PRIMARY KEY (course_id, instructor_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES grade(course_id)
);
```

When I try to create the 3rd table I get this error. Is it because of the composite primary key in the grade table? How do I fix this?

Comment: You are definitely not using MySQL, but Oracle DB. Please confirm which RDBMS are you using ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle (ORA-02270) : no matching unique or primary key for this column-list error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802212/oracle-ora-02270-no-matching-unique-or-primary-key-for-this-column-list-erro)

Comment: sql server?? sorry this is all new to me so still all a bit confusing!

Comment: You don't know which dbms you are using???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary key in GRADE covers two columns: `stu_id` and `course_id`. You cannot use `course_id` as a reference from the COURSE table, because it could potentially reference multiple rows.

Your foreign key should be in the `GRADE` table instead:

```
CREATE TABLE GRADE(
    stu_id NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
    course_id VARCHAR2(7),
    stu_crse_grade VARCHAR2(1),
    PRIMARY KEY (stu_id, course_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (stu_id) REFERENCES students(stu_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES course(course_id),
    CHECK (stu_crse_grade = 'A' 
    AND stu_crse_grade = 'B' 
    AND stu_crse_grade = 'C' 
    AND stu_crse_grade = 'D' 
    AND stu_crse_grade = 'F')
);
```

Additionally, for your `COURSE` table, your primary key needs to be NOT NULL, and should only encompass the `course_id` field. If you could potentially have multiple course_id's for different instructors, how is `GRADE.course_id` going to distinguish which course I'm in, if I don't supply an `instructor_id`?

```
CREATE TABLE COURSE(
    course_id VARCHAR2(7) NOT NULL,
    course_title VARCHAR2(20),
    instructor_id NUMBER(3),
    PRIMARY KEY (course_id)
);
```

Comment: i need to create 4 tables and all of them need to have a PK and FK. When I try to run your version of the grade table it won't create it since course table does not exist yet

Comment: @betty Create the COURSE table first (It shouldn't have any references).

Comment: I created the COURSE table first, then STUDENTS, and when I tried to create the GRADE table I got the same error..

Comment: Thanks so much! IDK why but I assumed I had to create the STUDENTS table first?? But it worked just fine when I created the COURSE table first and STUDENTS second.

Comment: The only order that matters is that GRADE comes after the other 2. The thing to remember: You should always be referencing the primary key from another table. The table with alternate column keys (In this case GRADE) should be the ones that have the references. If this answered all your questions, don't forget to leave the green checkmark.