# Oracle keep unique constraint index

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, toad

When I drop a `unique` column (just unique not primary key) constraint, Toad prompts me whether if I want to keep the index.

To me the logical thing is to remove the index but why does it offer to keep it ? Is it for saving time if I make the same column unique at a later point in time ? (which kind of confuses me since the old index may cause conflicts).

Comment: read some considerations at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521817/oracle-unique-constraint-and-unique-index-question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521817/oracle-unique-constraint-and-unique-index-question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of 10g, Oracle introduced the "KEEP INDEX" option on `ALTER TABLE...DROP CONSTRAINT`.  From what I've read, it should be the other way around...in that it should drop the index unless you specify "KEEP INDEX".  So I am assuming that you removed the index via the GUI menus.

With that in mind, the TOAD GUI was probably designed to prompt you for that.  I wonder if you actually ran `ALTER TABLE...DROP CONSTRAINT` if it would still prompt you.  I am going to bet "not."

Comment: Yes running queries directly from editor does not cause any prompts (for everything actually)

Comment: I still wonder though: why would someone want to keep the index after dropping the constraint ?

Comment: I suppose it would be a rare situation, but I think it's more intended for removing a foreign key constraint. That way you could remove the constraint if you didn't want to enforce referential integrity between two tables.  But you might still have it in some JOIN/WHERE clauses buried in application code.