# Unique case insensitive constraint in oracle database

Tags: oracle

I have a `varchar` column in my table for url value. I have to make it unique across the records case-insensitively.
I found 2 ways to achieve it.

1. Create an unique index on the field.

   ```
   create unique index <index_name> on <tablename>(lower(<column_name>))
   ```
2. Add a unique constraint on the field as

   ```
   ALTER TABLE person ADD CONSTRAINT person_name_unique
   UNIQUE(LOWER(first_name),LOWER(last_name));
   ```

What is the efficient way to adopt from the above choices ?

Comment: This is a pretty comprehensive explanation of the difference, without commenting explicitly on efficiency: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7522004/110933

Comment: A unique constraint use a unique index under the hood, there is no difference betwen them, the only difference is the syntax.

Comment: I would prefer the constraint; the difference is in semantics. A future developer might consider the constraint as a form of documentation: "this must be case-insensitive unique". A unique index, OTOH, might be construed as being merely created for performance purposes: "this column happens to always be case-insensitive unique"

Answer (score 16):

The more efficient approach is the first approach.  It's more efficient, though, only because the latter syntax doesn't work.  You cannot, unfortunately, create a function-based constraint in the same way that you can create a unique index.

A unique constraint doesn't work

```
SQL> create table person (
  2    first_name varchar2(10),
  3    last_name  varchar2(10)
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> ALTER TABLE person ADD CONSTRAINT person_name_unique
  2  UNIQUE(LOWER(first_name),LOWER(last_name));
UNIQUE(LOWER(first_name),LOWER(last_name))
       *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
```

A unique function-based index, however, does work

```
SQL> create unique index idx_uniq_name
  2      on person( lower(first_name), lower(last_name) );

Index created.
```

Comment: Thanks, so, if we create a unique function-based index, then we do not need to / we should not add a unique constraint on the column?

Comment: @user1116119 - You can't create a unique constraint on the function value, just a unique function-based index.  Depending on your Oracle version, you should also be able to create a computed column that is `lower(first_name)` and create a unique constraint on that.

Comment: One thing it's worth adding - you can't reference the unique index directly in an ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT, but you can reference the condition (e.g. ON CONFLICT (LOWER(first_name), LOWER(last_name)). Tripped me up today, and this is the first result on Google for the question, so figured I'd mention it...

Answer (score 0):

- 1 is possible and gives error for duplicate.
- 2 is not possible. (function is not possible in constraint)